# Toggle between 2 gmail calendars?

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-2, google-account, google-calendar

I would like to have 2 separate gmail calendars, one for work and one for personal.  I have 2 different gmail accounts but I can only find how to sync them together instead of going back and forth between.  Is it possible to keep them separate but both still visible on my phone?

Comment: Are you using the samsung calendar app? or the google calendar app?

Comment: @MattClark The question is tagged with "google-calendar"

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way on the stock Calendar app. However you can do this by using two different Calendar apps.